# Showing message in a razor view based on a result from execution of controller method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on asp.net mvc 3 application. I'm implementing a razor view which have tow main functions - to build/display form based on a data from a data base and to show images related to this form in a custom (made by me) image gallery that allows upload and delete of image.

So generally this is my view with both forms for visualizing the form and showing and uploading image(s) :

```
@model List<DataAccess.MCS_DocumentFields>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Документ";
}
<div id="alabala">
<div id="drawForm">
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateDocument", "Forms", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table border="1" id="drawDocument">
        <colgroup>
            <col span="1" style="width: 10%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 40%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 25%;" />
            <col span="1" style="width: 25%;" />
        </colgroup>
        @Html.Partial("_PartialHeader", Model)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialDrawing", Model)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialBody", Model)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialFooter", Model)

    </table>
    if (ViewBag.Status == 1)
    {
        <button type="submit" id="submitDocument">Запази</button> 
        <button style="float:right;" id="finalizeDocument">Приключи</button>  
    }
    else
    { 
        @Html.ActionLink("Назад", "Index")
    }
}
</div>
<div id="imageContainer">
<div id="imageGallery" style="overflow: scroll">
 <img src="file:\\..." alt="docImg" style="width: 190px; height: auto"/>
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePicture", new { documentID = Model[0].Id },
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            Confirm = "Are you sure?",
                            OnComplete = "$('#blah').attr('src', '#').attr('style', 'display:none;'); $('#Image1').attr('src', '#').attr('style', 'display:none;'); $('#DelPic').attr('style', 'display:none;');"
                        })
 <img src="file:\\..." alt="docImg" style="width: 190px; height: auto"/>
  @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePicture", new { documentID = Model[0].Id },
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            Confirm = "Are you sure?",
                            OnComplete = "$('#blah').attr('src', '#').attr('style', 'display:none;'); $('#Image1').attr('src', '#').attr('style', 'display:none;'); $('#DelPic').attr('style', 'display:none;');"
                        })
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Forms", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <input name=@Model[0].DocumentId type="hidden" />

    <input type="file" name="datafile" id="file" onchange="readURL(this);" />
    <input type="button" name="Button" value="Upload" id="UploadButton" onclick="fileUpload(this.form,'/forms/upload','upload'); return false;"/>
    <div id="upload" style="display: inline-block;">
        <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" style="display:none;"/>
    </div>
}
</div>
</div>
```

The first form is where I show the data for a current form/document and because they are editable I have submit button. I need the second form to submit the selected picture to my controller and there to perform the business logic.

So once a picture is selected and `Upload` button is clicked I get to my controller :

```
public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection collection)
        {
            WebImage UploadImage = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
            long documentID;
            string finalImageName = null;
            if (!long.TryParse(collection.AllKeys[0], out documentID))
            //More code...
```

Where I have the image and the id of the document that it belongs to and what I need is to perform some checks/validations and finally to coy the selected image to dedicated directory and save the name to the data base.

The problem is that I have all the logic written except the one that will show the correct messages for the different outputs like :

```
if (imagePath.Length > 247)
                            {
                                //TODO message that the path is too long
                                //TODO this return View() is temp, replace with something suitable
                                return View();
                            }
                    //...
                         System.IO.File.Copy(UploadImage.FileName, imagePath);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            //TODO copy failed return message
                            return View();
                        }
                    //...
```

These are all different outputs from the execution of the same method and in the main view I want to show a proper message for each one of them. What I'm not sure is if I still have an option to save my work and still implement the message logic? Thinking now it seems that if I was using Ajax in some form it would be a lot easier now but I'm not. The only think I can think of know is creating `ViewBag` property, and returning it with the model to the view where to check the different properties and show some message if necessary based on that, but this means a lot of additional logic in my view, resending data from the database that I already have shown in my view and a lot of double work said in short, something that I consider as a bad programming, but maybe I got myself into this. So what is the best course of action from here on. Is it best to just remove my code and search for a way to do this with AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't upload a file using AJAX - you'd need some sort of 3rd party workaround. You need to return the original view from the Upload() method, with the appropriate model, and also a flag within the ViewBag somewhere to display the message, e.g.

```
public ActionResult Upload(UpdateDocumentModel model) {
...
  if (imagePath.Length > 247) {
    model.ErrorMessage = Errors.Over247;
    return View("UpdateDocument", model);
  }
...
return RedirectToAction("UploadOk");
}
```

I've changed your `FormCollection` to a strongly-typed model for ease of reading, plus that's what MVC.net is there for. The `Errors.Over247` could be a string resource somewhere in your project, or a boolean flag which the View then reads to show a certain piece of HTML.

Comment: You don't need a ViewBag, that's just for illustration, you can add the "Message" property onto the UpdateDocumentModel you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

just use TempData instead of ViewBag

```
TempData["ErorrMessegge"] = "SomeMessage to view";


@TempData["ErorrMessegge"]
```

Comment: Hmm, I haven't seen `TempData` before is that keyword in asp.net mvc ?

Comment: its a TempDataDictionary property of asbstract class ControllerBase. Data in this dictionary "live" just in current request.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use TempData[] in order to pass parameter from Controller to View like below:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Applicant applicant)
{
    repository.SaveApplicant(applicant);
    TempData["message"] = "The applicant has been saved succesfully.";
    return View(applicant);
}
```

**View:**

```
@if (TempData["message"] != null)
{
    <div>@TempData["message"]</div>
}
```